# Printer error on server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have a Print Server configured on Server 2012 R2 Standard. I have installed HP printer on it. When i redirected all the Printers. Users are not able to print form the printer. It shows below error "a policy is in effect on your computer which prevents you to connecting to this print queue please contact your administrator" 
As i go through HP forum it tells that to uninstall some updates but on my server i not installed any update.
Locally i am able to Print properly.

Comment: I remove the windows update KB3197868 but same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to configure the following policies in your default domain policy. After configuring the policies you should run the command: gpupdate /force.

User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Printers\

Point and Print Restrictions >>Disable
Prevent addition of printers >> Disable
Prevent deletion of printers >>Disable

Local Computer Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers\

Allow print spooler to accept client connections >> Enable

If the issue persists, you may also refer to the following link to troubleshoot this issue:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888046/en-us